my SIC assembly program is printing 00 00 00 as an output
here is the SIC code, it is printing 00 00 00 to device 64 when I run it inside the SIC simulator provided to me:
CLOCK    START   3072
T        WORD    48500
D        WORD    64
H        RESW    1
M        RESW    1
F        RESW    1
P        RESB    1
TMP      RESB    1
A        BYTE    C'A'
P2       BYTE    C'P'

         LDA     T
         AND     #8000
         STA     F

         LDA     T
         AND     #7FFF
         DIV     #3600
         STA     H
         STX     TMP

         LDA     TMP
         DIV     #60
         STA     M
         STX     TMP

         LDA     F
         COMP    #8000
         JEQ     P24

         LDA     H
         COMP    #12
         JLT     AM
         SUB     #12
         STA     H
         LDA     P2
         STA     P
         J       P12

AM       LDA     A
         STA     P

P12      LDA     H
         COMP    #10
         JLT     SH12
         SUB     #10
         ADD     #48
         STA     TMP
         LDCH    TMP
         WD      D
         LDA     H
         ADD     #48
         LDCH    0
         WD      D
         J       M12

SH12     LDA     H
         ADD     #48
         LDCH    0
         WD      D

M12      LDA     M
         COMP    #10
         JLT     SM12
         SUB     #10
         ADD     #48
         STA     TMP
         LDCH    TMP
         WD      D
         LDA     M
         ADD     #48
         LDCH    0
         WD      D
         J       PD

SM12     LDA     M
         ADD     #48
         LDCH    0
         WD      D

PD       LDA     P
         LDCH    0
         WD      D
         RSUB

P24      LDA     H
         COMP    #10
         JLT     SH24
         SUB     #10
         ADD     #48
         STA     TMP
         LDCH    TMP
         WD      D
         LDA     H
         ADD     #48
         LDCH    0
         WD      D
         J       M24

SH24     LDA     H
         ADD     #48
         LDCH    0
         WD      D

M24      LDA     M
         COMP    #10
         JLT     SM24
         SUB     #10
         ADD     #48
         STA     TMP
         LDCH    TMP
         WD      D
         LDA     M
         ADD     #48
         LDCH    0
         WD      D
         RSUB

SM24     LDA     M
         ADD     #48
         LDCH    0
         WD      D
         RSUB

         END     CLOCK

already tried:
Ensured proper handling of the timer value, particularly splitting it into hours and minutes using the remaining seconds. Adjusted for 12-hour and 24-hour format selection based on the most significant bit of the timer value. Ensured hours and minutes are converted into proper ASCII values using ADD #48. Used LDCH to load a byte before sending it to the device via WD

Expected output: for 12-hour format: 01:28P (31 3A 30 31 3A 32 38 50 in ASCII)
                 for 24-hour format: 13:28 (31 33 3A 32 38 in ASCII)


Show us where it goes wrong — like on what line of code — and what you don't understand about why it is not doing what you think it should?

@ErikEidt it prints 00 when it reaches the WD lines -where it supposed to print the value to the device-. I don't understand why it's printing zeros instead of the correct value

For starters, it's unclear what base your numbers are in. AND #7FFF suggests hex, but then DIV #3600 makes little sense as 3600 should be decimal if it's the number of seconds in an hour (but of course your code is not commented so we can only guess). It's also unclear why you mask to 7FFF because that is 32767 seconds so does not cover half a day.

Ok, that's a good start at debugging.  What's in the register when the WD executes?  Is it an ascii '0'?  If so, can you work backwards to identify who/what code generated that and what value it should have been?  There are (at least) two approaches for debugging, one is to work forward, e.g. from the start of the program, and verify every instruction (just one wrong or missing or extra instruction can make the whole program fail), and for mostly working code, we can (logically) work backward to find out who/what code gave some other code bad data to work with.

Your data is ahead of your code — often we put data after the code, or sometimes, have a first instruction (right after START) that jumps around the data to the first line of code.  Can you tell from your simulator, what is the first instruction to execute?

A combination like this seems to be mixing sizes: STA TMP; LDCH TMP, so the STA will store 2 bytes and the LDCH load one of them, only the first byte.

I don't understand the LDCH 0 that you have in several places.
